# repeatAction doesn't animate

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

Animation doesn't work if I run action forever, but if I run it only once it works fine.

```
func go() {
    var block = SKAction.runBlock { self.animate(index: self.random(), wait: 5.7) }
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(block))
}

func animate(# index: Int, wait: Double) {
    let anim = SKAction.animateWithTextures([
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "img1"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "img2"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "img3"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "img4")],
        timePerFrame: 0.03)

    let pop = SKAction.repeatAction(anim, count: 1)
    sequence = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.repeatAction(pop, count: 1),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(0.7)])

    item[index].runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(sequence, count: 1), completion: toggleTouch)
    println(index) //this line works fine
}
```

I guess it continues to execute new action, before previous animation completes, but how do I go about this?

Comment: I think you want to repeat the entire action sequence, not just the 1 action maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite complicated. Try this one and let me know if my provided code can not satisfy your game feature.

> let anim = SKAction.animateWithTextures([
>           SKTexture(imageNamed: "img1"),
>           SKTexture(imageNamed: "img2"),
>           SKTexture(imageNamed: "img3"),
>           SKTexture(imageNamed: "img4")],
>           timePerFrame: 0.03)

```
func go() {
    self.animate(index: self.random(), wait: 5.7);
}

func animate(# index: Int, wait: Double) {
    let actionFinish = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
        // toggleTouch()  is called here before println
        println(index) //this line works fine
    }

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([
        anim,
        SKAction.waitForDuration(wait),  // or 0.7 as your code
        actionFinish
        ]);

    item[index].runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unclear and so is your question. Put more information so we can actually help.